# Unable to cast object of type NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag to List

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class called ReportRequest as:

```
public class ReportRequest
{
    Int32 templateId;
    List<Int32> entityIds;

    public virtual Int32? Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Int32 TemplateId
    {
        get { return templateId; }
        set { templateId = value; }
    }

    public virtual List<Int32> EntityIds
    {
        get { return entityIds; }
        set { entityIds = value; }
    }

    public ReportRequest(int templateId, List<Int32> entityIds)
    {
        this.TemplateId = templateId;
        this.EntityIds = entityIds;
    }
}
```

It is mapped using Fluent Hibernate as:

```
public class ReportRequestMap : ClassMap<ReportRequest>
{
    public ReportRequestMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(null).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.TemplateId).Not.Nullable();            
        HasMany(x => x.EntityIds).Table("ReportEntities").KeyColumn("ReportRequestId").Element("EntityId").AsBag().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

Now, I create an object of this class as

```
ReportRequest objReportRequest = new ReportRequest(2, new List<int>() { 11, 12, 15 });
```

and try to Save the object in database using

```
session.Save(objReportRequest);
```

I get the following error:
*"Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'.*"

I am not sure if I have mapped the property EntityIds correctly.
Please guide.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you want a list of ints and not a list of related entities?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Use collection interfaces instead of concrete collections, so NHibernate can inject it with its own collection implementation.

In this case, use `IList<int>` instead of `List<int>`

Comment: Thank you! solved the issue.
Can you please elaborate a little when you say 'NHibernate can inject it with its own collection implementation.'

Comment: It's explained here: http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/T_NHibernate_Collection_IPersistentCollection.htm

Comment: This link no longer exists. An updated one or the brief content would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Noich: http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Collection/IPersistentCollection.html

Comment: I am confused by the number of people on stackoverflow complaining about dead links. Has nobody heard of archive.org? https://web.archive.org/web/20091105034326/http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate.Collection/IPersistentCollection.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `ICollection<T>` worked where `IList<T>` did not.

I'm no NHibernate wizard, but I did want to throw a bone to someone else who might land on this issue.

Comment: It depends on how your collection is mapped. For `bag` you can use `IList<T>` and for set - `ISet<T>`