# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I recently upgraded Windows SmartClient solution from nHibernate 2.2 to 4.0 and am getting an exception when writing to the db.

The exception is thrown at this code:

```
this.session.Save(this.Location); // NHibernate.ISession
tx.Commit(); // exception thrown here
```

The exception is:

> 'System.InvalidCastException' in NHibernate.dll
>   System.InvalidCastException: 
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' 
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'.

There are several lists in the object being saved, here is a couple representative ones:

```
protected System.Collections.IList locationList;
public virtual System.Collections.IList AssociatedLocationList
{
    get
    {
        if (this.locationList == null)
        {
            this.locationList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
        }
        return this.locationList;
    }
    set { this.locationList = value; }
}
protected System.Collections.Generic.IList<Inspection> inspectionList;
public virtual System.Collections.Generic.IList<Inspection> InspectionList
{
    get
    {
        if (this.inspectionList == null)
        {
            this.inspectionList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Inspection>();
        }

        return this.inspectionList;
    }
    set { this.inspectionList = value; }
}
```

Note that some have a type specified and some don't.

One suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808978/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-nhibernate-collection-generic-persistentgenericba) is set the property to an `IList`, but I already have it as that.

What can be done?

Comment: Have you considered using generics on this?  Tossing around bare objects seems very... 2003.

Comment: I added another representative property that has a <T> to the original post. Are you suggesting that not having this could cause the problem?

Comment: The cast would no longer exist in a generic version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for persistent non-generic collections was removed in NHibernate 4.0. Convert to generic collection instead.

See list of breaking changes in [NHibernate 4.0 release notes](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/4.0.x/releasenotes.txt).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here could be with latest version of NHibernate ..i.e. 4.0

you have following options.

1) Most of the time, new version support backward compatibility. If it is the case, look for overload versions of iSession.Save method. You may get non-generic as well.

2) Possibly new save method only support generic type. Yours is non-generic i.e. ArrayList. If you can change it to Ilist<>, that should help.

3) If you do not have control on Ilis, then you may write converter in between which can convert your Arraylist to Ilist<> and it would work with Save method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Based on what you and @Robert Harvey have said, I am working on #2. This may take a while.This code is 10 years old.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding your question right and if so, I'm not sure you need to be doing your null check at all.  Instead your parent class should have a list of locations that are held in another table entirely.

**This is class in which your location list is.**

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    //This is the mapping for this class.
    public class ParentMapping : ClassMap<Parent>
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();

        //This is what relates your location list to this parent.
        //Notice that in the Location object below, 
        //there's a Owner property which will point back to here.
        HasMany(x => x.Locations).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

**And this is the class that defines your locations.**

```
public class Location
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    //This is the mapping for this class.
    public class LocationMapping : ClassMap<Location>
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.SomeProperty);

        //This will relate our property back to the parent.
        References(x => x.Owner);
    }
}
```