# Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, ilist

I am trying to load the domain class by deserializing an xml file. So I have used System.Collections.Generic.List in the domain class. But when I try to save the object using Session object then it is failing with exception "Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[MyFirstMapTest.Class5]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyFirstMapTest.Class5]'." This issue was posted in some of the previous discussion and the answer was to use use IList instead of List([Unable to cast object of type NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638593/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-nhibernate-collection-generic-persistentgenericbag))

But, If I use IList then I am unable to Deserialize the xml in to Domain class.

```
XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Temp\SampleInput.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objClass5.GetType());
objClass5 = (MyFirstMapTest.Class5)serializer.Deserialize(xtr);
session.Save(objClass5);
```

It is throwing the below error
"Cannot serialize member xxxxx of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[xxxxxxxxxx, Examples, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface."

I have tried to use PersistentGenericBag instead of List but PersistentGenericBag is not serializable. So Deserialization is not working.

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you for looking at this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create two properties like this in your class:

```
public class Sample
{
    private IList<Sample> _list;

    [XmlIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual IList<Sample> List
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual List<Sample> List
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<Sample>)_list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you only map your IList Property.

Comment: This is giving me type cast error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ListUCMFXsdGenFile.AssessmentSourceEntry>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ListUCMFXsdGenFile.AssessmentSourceEntry>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use backing field for NHibernte binding and property for Serialization, where property will be of type List, while backing field - IList.

**Edit**
fluent mapping may look like this:

```
public class HierarchyLevelMap : IAutoMappingOverride<HierarchyLevel>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<HierarchyLevel> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.StructuralUnits)
            .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField();
    }
}
```

entity:

```
public class HierarchyLevel : IEntity
{
    private readonly IList<StructuralUnit> structuralUnits = new List<StructuralUnit>();

    public virtual List<StructuralUnit> StructuralUnits
    {
        get { return structuralUnits; }
        set { structuralUnits = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use backing field? Is that a private property? Do you have a sample?

Comment: I have added some examples, Could you please check?

Comment: This is giving me type cast error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<ListUCMFXsdGenFile.AssessmentSourceEntry>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ListUCMFXsdGenFile.AssessmentSourceEntry>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"